# ASP.NET MVC populating a dynamic textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of learning and understanding asp.net MVC and google maps.. Just came across one of the examples while googling and got a doubt.

Here's what I am trying to do...

in the form there are 3 things... a dynamic texbox, a submit button and  "my location" button which I am trying to add.

on clicking the "my location" button,( I have the javascript to get the lat, long of my coordinates) it should display it on the textbox, just wanted to see whether it has picked up properly and then i will click on the submit button.

I saw in the code referred as `<%html.texbox('addr')%>` I presume it is dynamic texbox...

Is this possible ? I think it should be, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: you can just pass the reference from javascript function to the box

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by Dynamic Textbox? a textbox every time a user clicks the button?
<%html.texbox('addr')%> syntax is something which is used to render a textbox and this aint a dynamic one. this is rendered only once when the complete view is being rendered. You can read more about input extentions in asp.net MVC view engines here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox.aspx
i you want to really insert a dynamic textbox whenver you click the button you can just use Jquery(already present in a new MVC project made by VS). and do something like

```
$('#divId').append($('<input type="text"/>'))
```

you can do smthing like

```
var $tb = $('<input type="text" value="SOme_Value_Lat,LON"/>');
$('#divId').append($tb);
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. so my assumption is wrong that's not the dynamic texbox.. but I cannot see that in the design view. I thought it should be dynamic. So coming back to my question.. on clicking the button it should assign the values to the textbox.. so you mean .append should do let me try.. thanks